# navigation controller is null when pushing new view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a tab bar application and in one of those tabs I have a map view. I am trying to push a new view from clicking a disclosure button on an annotation on the map view using this code...

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

childController = [[AnnotationDetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnnotationDetailView" bundle:nil];       

[self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];

}
```

however if I nslog the navigationController it is null.

What is confusing is that in another tab I have a table view which will push a view using the above code. Why does that work but an map annotation doesn't.

Comment: you `nslog navigationController` from where?

Comment: After I try and push the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that your table view is inside a navigation controller and your map view isn't.  A tab view controller isn't actually a navigation controller itself.

Depending on your project, the fix may be as simple as editing your XIB so that a navigation controller is the immediate child of the tab controller for the map's tab, and the map view controller is the child of that navigation controller.  Look at how your table view is defined, and you should be able to see what's different.

Comment: I am new to this game, but trying to learn. Still not too sure, I guess I will need to read up a bit more.

Comment: Since I have set everything up in the interface builder. How do you mean look at how the tableview is defined. Do you mean what class it conforms to?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard to give you useful details, since there are dozen ways to have arrive at your situation.  Ultimately, there is somewhere that your tableview gets "added" to the tab controller. If you look closely at wherever that is, you'll see that a navigation controller is actually getting added to the tab controller, and the tableviewcontroller is getting added to that nav controller.  In the simplest example, you'd be able to see this hierarchy in the document window of your MainWindow.xib and you'd be able to mimic it for your map view.  But your situation may be more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `childController` as **`AnnotationDetailView * childController;`** in your header?

or you can simply use:

```
AnnotationDetailView * childController = [[AnnotationDetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnnotationDetailView" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that